# Java Compiling issue when first using vscode

Tags: java, class, visual-studio-code, compilation

I have been using vmware to log into the lab machines at my uni. I just started using vscode on my pc. I installed latest jdk 16.0 and i installed the java extension pack from vscode. But it still wont let me run or compile my program

I keep getting this error, thought it was an issue about the paths after a little bit of research so i made the java:home path to where jdk folder is in my c drive and i still get this error:

```
c:; cd 'c:\Users\Aaron Mark\Desktop\UNI\FinalAssignment'; & 'c:\Users\Aaron Mark\.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.34.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.1\bin\java.exe' '--enable-preview' '-XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\Aaron Mark\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\2bfa7b3e373492b1fc42e07c42d17320\redhat.java\jdt_ws\FinalAssignment_fe08a03d\bin' 'QuestionOnePartA
```

How do i fix this class not found error?

Comment: Could you include the full error you are getting, as well as any relevant information about your project layout?

Comment: What error? I see no error in that question text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you point to the blue sentences displayed before the real output, actually they are not errors but execution scripts, which shows the necessary building and compiling commands to get the output:

[image]

If you don't want to see these scripts but pure output, [create a launch.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-debugging#_configure) and add `"console": "externalTerminal",` in configurations. **Run without debugging(Ctrl+F5)** can open a new external Terminal and no execution scripts shown:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not error.
IDE is printing all the program being used for compiling and running the code.

'-cp' : this is your classpath. You can add more external library using it.